# More than half of the screen is black with tiny code on Acer aspire one

Tags: system-installation, screen, acer

I just replaced Windows XP with Ubuntu on my Acer aspire one laptop using the usb installation method and now more than half of the screen is black with unreadable writing or code. I'm new to Ubuntu, hopefully it's an easy fix. Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you somehow add an image to your description?